# Setting document file icon in Xcode not working?

Tags: xcode, macos, icons, document

I'm trying to associate the type of files that my app uses (extension `.sbd`) with my app, and have the saved file show a customized document icon. I've set up the Document Types section in Xcode as shown below:
[image: Xcode Doc types settings]

Here is my `Info.plist` section for the document types:

[image: info.plist]

I've looked at other similar questions on here, but they either mention `CFBundleTypeIconFile`, which appears to be deprecated, or they fail to resolve the issue. Is there something I'm not doing, or doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your `.icns` file stored in your app bundle? It should be in `Resources` if already not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting up `CFBundleTypeRole` as `Viewer`. Your `Info.plist` must look like this:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>sbd</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>SBDocumentIcon</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>icns</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Clean & rebuild your project. In case the icons do not update, try restarting your computer.

Comment: Actually, it did work, it just took a little while to go into effect. Perhaps it needed to rebuild a database or something?

Comment: yeap, the mac iconcache must be refreshed and sometimes takes a bit. If restarting doesn't work there are ways to restart it from Command-Line with touch https://gist.github.com/fabiofl/5873100